# Java - Regex: Several matches in same string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string: `String s = "The input must be of format: '$var1$'-'$var1$'-'$var1$'"`.

I want to replace the text between the `$` with another text, so the outcome may look on the console like:
`"The input must be of format: '$REPLACED$'-'$REPLACED$'-'$REPLACED$'"`

I came till `s.replaceAll("\\$.+\\$", "\\$REPLACED\\$";`, but that results in
`"The input must be of format: '$REPLACED$'"` (the first and the last `$` are taken as borders).

How can I tell the regex engine, that there are several occurences and each need to be processed (=replaced)?

Thank for your help!

**Edit://** Thanks for your help. The "greedy thing" was the matter. Adding a `?` to the regex fixed my issue. The solution now looks like this (for those witha similar problem):
`s.replaceAll("\\$.+?\\$", "\\$REPLACED\\$";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect you're experiencing is called *greediness*: An expression like `.+` will match as many characters as possible.

Use `.+?` instead to make the expression *ungreedy* and match as few characters as possible.

Answer (score 2):

`+` is *greedy* so it will try to find maximal match. This means that `[$].+[$]` will match

```
a$b$c$e
 ^^^^^
```

If you want `.+` to look for minimal possible match you can

- add `?` after `+` quantifier `.+?` making `+` reluctant
- instead of every character (`.`) between `$ $` accept only these that are **not** `$` like `[^$]`.

So try to change your regex to

```
s.replaceAll("\\$.+?\\$", "\\$REPLACED\\$");
```

or

```
s.replaceAll("\\$[^$]+?\\$", "\\$REPLACED\\$");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
String s = "The input must be of format: '$var1$'-'$var1$'-'$var1$'";
System.out.println( s.replaceAll("\\$[^$]*\\$", "\\$REPLACED\\$") );
//=> The input must be of format: '$REPLACED$'-'$REPLACED$'-'$REPLACED$'
```

Using this regex: `\\$[^$]*\\$` will match literal `$` then string until `$` is found and then followed by literal `$`